# Добавление нового статуса наличия товара Magento 2

Tags: magento

Здравствуйте!
Интересует решение вопроса о добавлении нового статуса наличия товара на складе Magento 2. Из коробки доступно 2 статуса: в наличии, нет на складе. Необходимо добавить еще несколько вариантов из серии "предзаказ" или "срок поставки 3-4 недели"... Где ковырять, и сложно ли само решение, т.к. есть платные модули но хотелось бы самому разобраться что к чему...? Magento 2.1.7

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Вы собираетесь написать полноценный модуль, который будет устанавливаться на разные магазины, или же этот код нужен исключительно для 1 проекта?

Comment: Только для одного проекта исключительно.

Answer (score 1):

Если только для одного проекта, то я бы рекомендовал сильно не заморачиваться и переписать (сделать реврайт) в собственном модуле для классов модуля `Magento_CatalogInventory` в которых упоминается `Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK`, `Stock::STOCK_IN_STOCK`, `Status::STATUS_OUT_OF_STOCK` и `Status::STATUS_IN_STOCK` заменив основную логику своей.

Основные классы на которые следует обращать внимание:

- `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Source\Stock` - варианты сток статусов используемые для вывода списков. Тут можно добавить свои дополнительно и в теории они должны сразу отобразиться в формах.
- `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock` - основная ресурсная модель инвентаря. Обратите внимание на запросы, в которых напрямую используется 1 или 0, обычно для определения и изменения сток статуса. Их следует модифицировать согласно вашим потребностям и дополнительным статусам.
- `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\Stock\DefaultStock` - индекс для инвентаря, так же потребует небольших правок для поддержки произвольных статусов.

В целом можно внутри этого модуля поискать по строкам `stock_status`, `in_stock`, `out_of_stock` и посмотреть где вносить правки. Я думаю это достаточно долгий процесс, т.к. в базовой мадженте не предусмотрена такая возможность из коробки и практически везде (в том числе в других модулях) проверка статуса происходит по 0 и 1, что, вероятно, потребует дополнительных правок для сторонних модулей или модулей мадженты где сток статус используется в проверках.

Comment: Спасибо! Мощно! Попробую позаморачиваться.

Comment: @AndreyKolomoets пишите, если будут какие-нибудь вопросы - я постараюсь помочь.